# Imacro regex to remove everything after specific word

Tags: regex

I m trying to remove everything that comes after "Related Posts" from imacro extraction.But i m not getting any result by my regex code.How can i get my exact result.Here is my code below

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:postcontent Extract=TXT
SET !VAR1 EVAL("var s=\"{{!EXTRACT}}\"; s.replace(/(?=Related posts\\:)[^Related posts\\:]*$/,\" \"); ")
Prompt {{!VAR1}
```

}

Comment: Try `s.replace(/Related posts:.*/,\"Related posts: \");`. If there are newline symbols, replace `.*` with `[\s\S]*` (or `[\\s\\S]*`). This regex will remove everything after the first `Related posts:`, not from the last occurrence of it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to remove everything after the first `Related posts:`, not from the last occurrence of it.

Thus, you can use

```
s.replace(/Related posts:.*/,\"Related posts: \")
```

If there are newline symbols, replace `.*` with `[\\s\\S]*`.